# Use JavaScript to change source of <iframe>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script>
 var URL = prompt("Insert URL here", "http://www.example.com"); //Asks user for URL
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <iframe onload="this.src=URL" height="610px" width="1320" id="window"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make the file load a URL into `<iframe>`, but when it finishes loading the URL, it reloads because of the `onload` attribute. Is there another attribute I should use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to use an iframe on an online editor because of the sandbox environment but it'll behave normal under normal conditions. As a valid test, you can enter `http://example.com` it's whitelisted.

**UPDATE**

Added a **[PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/n0kXnz0YXIZWmdTGEKrV/)** since SO sandboxes iframes.

**EDIT**

I added another way to manipulate the iframe you might be interested in. Itonly involves HTML, no JS. Notice the `anchor` to example.com. Basically all you need to do is the following:

1. Add a `name` attribute to the iframe (I always have id and name the same)
2. On the anchor, you change the `target` attribute  value to the value of the iframe's `name` value.

So in this demo the part inside `{{{...}}}` is the trick. The brackets are added for emphasis do not include them into the code to use.

```
<a href="http://example.com" {{{target="site"}}}>Example.com</a>

<iframe id="site" {{{name="site"}}} src="/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

```js
function changeSrc(src) {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('site');
  iframe.src = src;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onchange="changeSrc(url.value);">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter URL</legend>
    <input id="url">


  </fieldset>
</form>
<a href="https://example.com" target="site">Example.com</a>
<section>
  <iframe id="site" name="site" src="/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</section>
```

Comment: What does the "/" value for source do?

Comment: It points to `root` in this example `root` is: `stacksnippets.net`  I think.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var URL = prompt("Insert URL here", "http://www.example.com"); //Asks user for URL
            if(URL) document.getElementById('window').src = URL;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <iframe height="610px" width="1320" id="window">
    </body>
</html>
```

the onload attribute you had on your iframe is fired when the iframe loads (and not when the page window loads), hence it setting the src again and then reloading the page into an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script>
 var URL = prompt("Insert URL here", "http://www.example.com"); //Asks user for URL
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <iframe onload="this.src=URL" height="610px" width="1320" id="window"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

We can accomplish this by using java's DOM changing methods.
To get the SRC of something, you can type

```
document.getElementById('window').src = URL;
```

This will acquire the SRC attribute of the elemnt with the ID '#window', and then change the attribute to whatever you set it to.

Just be sure that the user enters a string.

Comment: I tried that, but when I use that, the <iframe> turns up blank.