# Random URL for Iframe on page load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i'm trying to load random iframe on my website 
i got a script

```js
var cat1 = [
    "http://arborjs.org",
    "http://cartodb.com",
    "http://vis4.net/labs/185"
    ];

var myFrame = document.getElementById("frame");

function getRandomUrl(myFrame) {
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*cat1.length);
   var url = cat1[index];
   myFrame.src = url;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
   getRandomUrl(myFrame); 
    
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<br>
<iframe id="frame" src="" style="width:200px; height: 200px"></iframe>
```

It works fine when i click the button, 
but i also want to load random iframe when the page finishes to load.

Can anyone edit this code for me ?
thank you

Comment: I answered a simular question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33742261/2813224)

Comment: You just need to attach a function to `window.onload`, and from there call your `getRandomUrl` function. Check my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

`widnow.onload` is your friend in this case:

```
window.onload = function(){
    getRandomUrl(myFrame);
};
```