# How to open a link to an another link using target="(iframe name)"?

Tags: html, button, iframe

I would like to iframe a specific links using the

```
<input type="button1" value="Button 1">
```

and the another button code is

```
<input type="button2" value="Button 2">
```

And on click, I would like to link an iframe into an another link on button1 and the other button will be linked to another link to be displayed via iframe. How can I do that? What HTML code we should do that?

Comment: [It only works with `<a>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33742261/2813224) upvote it if it helped.